# How to check if user is connected in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to check if user is logged in directly in the view with blade ?
I know that i can use this in controller:

**PHP**

```
Auth::check()
```

Comment: You can use `Auth::check()` anywhere, not just in the controllers.

Comment: You can also use `auth()->check()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**PHP**

```
@if (Auth::check())
  I'm connected
@endif
```

Comment: This is correct. The only way this won't work is if the Middleware was not correctly applied to the route, but then it wouldn't work in the controller either.

Comment: make this question as answered pls